# copy all text from text file and insert it on the beginning of each line sed

Tags: file, text, sed, addition

I want to copy all the text in a text file and to add at the beginning of each line in another text file.

I have tried with sed, I can put a char at the beginning of each line but I don't how to copy text from another file

I have tried this:

```
sed 's/^/#/' 2.txt > 3.txt
```

but this puts only a char or a string.

Example:

I have in the 2.txt the words:

```
u
ubbia
ubbidiente
ubbidienza
ubbidire
ubertoso
```

in the second 3.txt I have the same lines but with explanation:

```
u  = explanation here
ubbia = explanation here
ubbidiente = explanation here
ubbidienza = explanation here
ubbidire = explanation here
ubertoso = explanation here
```

I want this result:

```
u              u  = explanation here
ubbia          ubbia = explanation here
ubbidiente     ubbidiente = explanation here
ubbidienza     ubbidienza = explanation here
ubbidire       ubbidire = explanation here
ubertoso       ubertoso = explanation here
```

Comment: `paste 2.txt 3.txt > combined.txt` may work for you. It will include a single tab char on each line between the different contents. If you really need it perfectly alligned, you can add something like  `awk '{printf "%15s\t%s\n", $1, $2}'` inbetween. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, this solution will make indentation in output as per length of maximum length of 1st column(a logic has been written for it), tested with given samples.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$1
  c[$1]
  next
}
($1 in c){
  b[++count]=$0
  len=len>length($1)?len:length($1)
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    val=len<length(b[i])?len+(len-length(a[i])):len
    printf("%s%"val"s%s\n",a[i],OFS,b[i])
  }
}
'  2.txt 3.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
u                   u  = explanation here
ubbia               ubbia = explanation here
ubbidiente          ubbidiente = explanation here
ubbidienza          ubbidienza = explanation here
ubbidire            ubbidire = explanation here
ubertoso            ubertoso = explanation here
```

Comment: @dani, it worked fine for me, can you check once if you have control M character in it by doing `cat -v Input_file`?

Comment: Yes. I have the M character. With the paste 2.txt 3.txt > combined.txt posted by shellter worked fine for me

Comment: @dani, Please remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and then try my code.

Comment: I tried it. Now works but not well. I find in the text the words but the words are not in line with the other words in the input file.

Comment: @dani, see my post I am getting correct Output, how are you getting it?

Comment: I am getting the same indentation, but my file is with 27000 lines and I am not getting the correct order with your code. I get this: ubbidiente               ubbia = explanation here.

Comment: I tested with your samples provided. Will see where I could tweak it more.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/.*/printf "%-15s" &/e;s#(\S+).*#s/^\\<\1\\>/&\1/#' file1 | 
sed -f - -e 't;d' file2
```

This builds a sed script from file1 and runs it against file2. If a line from file1 matches the first word for file2, the printf formatted line from file 1 is prepended to the matching line from file2, otherwise it is deleted. If you prefer to  leave unmatching lines from file2 alone, remove the `-e 't;d'` commands from the above solution.

N.B. This solution does not require either file to be sorted, however for large files it may be time intensive.

From your comments to jas, if the file is 1-1, this may work for you:

```
parallel -k 'printf "%-15s%s\n" {1} {2}' ::::+ file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks but the file is to big.

Comment: @dani if the files are one-to-one use the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the first file at all? Why not just:

```
$ awk '{print $1 "\t" $0}' 3.txt  | column -t -s $'\t'
u           u  = explanation here
ubbia       ubbia = explanation here
ubbidiente  ubbidiente = explanation here
ubbidienza  ubbidienza = explanation here
ubbidire    ubbidire = explanation here
ubertoso    ubertoso = explanation here
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have ubbia the first world in the first file, then ùbbia = explanation here in the second file. I can't just copy it, it will copy the accented letter too. Thanks for the answer